# Cannot implicitly convert A<B> to A<C<D>> where B inherit from C<D>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, architecture

I'm building a sort of library to perform text replacement in a document based on some rule. We built a POC and now I'm trying to create a library as generic as possible.

I have just one problem with inheritance:

This is the simplified representation of the classes/interfaces I'm dealing with:

```
public interface IRule {}

public interface IReplaceRule<T> : IRule 
{
    T ReplaceValue { get; set; }
}

public class CachedRules<T> where T : IReplaceRule<object>
{
    #region Props
    public T RuleTemplate { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, T> RuleList { get; private set; } = null;
    #endregion

    public void SetRuleList(IDictionary<string, T> ruleList) { ... }

    public bool ContainsRuleByKey(string key) { ... }

    public bool TryGetRuleValueByKey(string key, out T rule) { ... }
}

public class SingleRowRule : IReplaceRule<string> { ... }
```

I also have a class which is like a repository of rules, and inside it I can add as many `CachedRules` as I need:

```
public class RulesStorage : AbstractRulesStorage
{
    private CachedRules<SingleRowRule> singleRowRules;

    public RulesStorage() { ... }

    // Bunch of methods not useful for this question

    // Here I need to return a list of ChachedRule, but just ofr testing I tried to return only one
    public CachedRules<IReplaceRule<object>> GetCachedReplaceRules()
    {
        return singleRowRules;
    }
}
```

Inside this class I need a method to return all the `CachedRules` declared in the `RulesStorage`:
Unfortunately the `RulesStorage.GetCachedReplaceRules` method give me this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `TestLib.Model.CachedRules<TestLib.Rules.SingleRowRule>` to `TestLib.Model.CachedRules<TestLib.Abstractions.IReplaceRule<object>`

I really don't like the fact that I had to put `<object>` since `IReplaceRule` requires a generic  and also I'm stuck because I don't know how to return this list of `CachedRules` without getting this compilation error.

Do you have some idea? Do I have to organize the code differently in your opinion?

Hope I've made myself clear and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `IReplaceRule<object>` you can do it the way `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`. With that minor tweak in place, I create an implicit converter to go from `T` to `IReplaceRule` and the constraint in place now ensures I can actually do this safely.

I'm assuming you have a reason to have `private CachedRules<SingleRowRule> singleRowRules;` and can't just using `private CachedRules<IReplaceRule> singleRowRules;` which would remove the need for this extra conversion hop.

#### Code:

```
public interface IReplaceRule : IRule { object ReplaceValue { get; set; } }

public interface IReplaceRule<T> : IReplaceRule { new T ReplaceValue { get; set; } }

public class CachedRules<T> where T : IReplaceRule
{
    public IDictionary<string, T> RuleList { get; private set; } = new Dictionary<string, T>();

    //The key ingredient for a nice experience instead of just doing this in the method
    public static implicit operator CachedRules<IReplaceRule>(CachedRules<T> rules)
        => new CachedRules<IReplaceRule> { RuleList = rules.RuleList.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value as IReplaceRule) };
}

public class SingleRowRule : IReplaceRule<string>
{
    public string ReplaceValue { get; set; }
    object IReplaceRule.ReplaceValue { get => ReplaceValue; set => ReplaceValue = value as string; }
}

public class RulesStorage
{
    private CachedRules<SingleRowRule> singleRowRules = new CachedRules<UserQuery.SingleRowRule>();

    //FIXME: just for testing purposes
    public RulesStorage() => singleRowRules.RuleList.Add("Hello", new SingleRowRule { ReplaceValue = "World" });

    // Here I need to return a list of ChachedRule, but just ofr testing I tried to return only one
    public CachedRules<IReplaceRule> GetCachedReplaceRules() => singleRowRules;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Maverik! I'll try your proposal ASAP and I'll let you know!